# Azure login/sign up (SSO) with .NET API and Angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an angular app which I need to be able to allow users sign up with Azure Active Directory via my .NET Core API.

Is there any decent tutorials that anyone has followed and implemented something like this before?

Comment: Yes we can do it by use Ms graph api : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how to create a user in Azure portal:

[image]

As you can see, display name, alias and the initial password is required for create a user. And in your scenario, you want to have an api which can be called by your angular client to create user in Azure ad, so you can use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) in your api so that you can call ms graph api. Then  here's my test code and it worked for me.

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace WebAppMvc.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> createUserAsync(AdUser model)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var tenantId = "your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
            var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
            var clientSecret = "azure_ad_client_secret";
            var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

            var user = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                DisplayName = model.displayName,
                MailNickname = model.mailAlias,
                UserPrincipalName = model.mailAlias + "@your_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    Password = model.password
                }
            };

            var res = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
            
            return "success";
        }
    }

    public class AdUser {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string mailAlias { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

It requires you to have an azure ad app and create client secret for the aad app, follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) to do it. And then you need to add api permission for your aad app, follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#application-permission-to-microsoft-graph) to add `User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All` application type api permission.

Comment: Great answer. +1 for including real world use case like azure users :)